# Flutter - How change AppBar height and align title vertical center?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need change appbar height in my flutter app. I use this code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
      child: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false, 
        flexibleSpace: Container(),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.search),
            Icon(Icons.home),
            PopupMenuButton<String>(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                  PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: "1",
                    child: Text('Hello'),
                  ),
                  PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: "2",
                    child: Text('World'),
                  ),
                ]
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: Container());
}
```

this is my result:

[image]

The height has changed but I need to align the content vertically in the center.
I try this options, but it not working:

```
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false, 
        flexibleSpace: Container(),
        centerTitle: true,
```

Any advises?

Comment: and also use safeArea for more clear output

Comment: add `crossAxisAlignment:center` to your title row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/115b02f36456fe9579cb8daf092bd906

```dart
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final double appBarHeight = 120.0;
  @override
  get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(appBarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            elevation: 0,
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.search),
                Icon(Icons.home),
                PopupMenuButton<String>(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                    PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      value: "1",
                      child: Text('Hello'),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      value: "2",
                      child: Text('World'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black54,
              blurRadius: 15.0,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75))
        ],
        color:
            ThemeData.dark().appBarTheme.color ?? ThemeData.dark().primaryColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The class 'PreferredSizeWidget' can't be used as a mixin because it's neither a mixin class nor a mixin. Error occurs after using this answer ..Please refer to the link for more info. [https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=class_used_as_mixin#class_used_as_mixin]

Answer (score 16):

Set PreferredSize wrapping AppBar. Then set AppBar's toolBarHeight field matching to preferredSize.

```
appBar: PreferredSize(preferredSize: const 
        Size.fromHeight(120.0),
        child: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 120.0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          flexibleSpace: Container(),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          shape: const Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black12),
          ),
)
```

Comment: This is the proper answer!

Comment: this was useful

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            flexibleSpace: Container(),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.search),
                Icon(Icons.home),
                PopupMenuButton<String>(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                      PopupMenuItem<String>(
                        value: "1",
                        child: Text('Hello'),
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem<String>(
                        value: "2",
                        child: Text('World'),
                      ),
                    ]
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: Container());
 }
```

Comment: So basically putting appbar inside a Column with mainAxisAlignment to MainAxisAlignment.center did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
      child: AppBar(
           automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
           flexibleSpace: Container(),
           centerTitle: true,
      title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:25.0),
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
             Icon(Icons.search),
             Icon(Icons.home),
        PopupMenuButton<String>(
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
        PopupMenuItem<String>(
        value: "1",
        child: Text('Hello'),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem<String>(
        value: "2",
        child: Text('World'),
          ),
         ]
        )
       ],
      ),
     ),
    ),
   )
  ),
 );
}
```