# Flutter - Align AppBar title to top

Tags: flutter

I just want to align my AppBar's title to the top instead of to the middle.

```
AppBar(
      title : Text('TITLE'),
      toolbarHeight : 100
)
```

I'm surprised this simple question was never been asked before and hardly found a solution out there. So forgive me if this question should not be here. I'll delete it immediately if it is.

Comment: how about wrap your `Text` with `Align` widget? if its only for the title, not included for `leading`, and `actions`

Comment: @pmatatias not working either. there's no leading nor actions. just title

Comment: have you see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60001360/12838877 ?

Comment: ow... sorry, its align all appbar content.

Comment: @pmatatias he used preferredsize which i don't use because i have no bottom. the appbar content looked aligned vertically to the top because there's a bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the default height by using kToolbarHeight, then you can create a sized box of the same height and align the text inside that sized box

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Container(
                  height: kToolbarHeight,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(
                    "Some title",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )))),
    );
  }
}
```

I added red color just to show that the Container fills the AppBar.

[image: preview]

**Edit**

If you wish to give a specific height to the appear add the same height to the SizedBox too..

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 100,
              title: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(
                    "Some title",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )))),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview2]

Comment: i need to set the appbar height explicitly like in the question. and if i do that, your solution not working